# How to make mouse work as in live version?

Tags: usb, mouse, live-usb, configuration, 21.04

For a long time the mouse stop working as well as when Ubuntu was initially installed with 18.04. I've upgraded and I'm in 21.04 now.

When accessing a live version of 21.04, the mouse behavior is perfect, so I ask **if I can copy live config into the installed one, and what exactly should I copy? (in respect to the mouse configuration)**

Problems presented are:

The pointer get stuck for a second or so, it gets interruptions on the way I intend to go, it is hard to select words, even harder when I try only some characters.

I have done no special setup for my system, just upgraded it when new versions come along.

Comment: Ok, now my question is in bold  (and a little detail added) so it is clearer what I'm asking for...

Answer (score 0):

I have finally discovered that there was an application making the mouse work with some difficulties. It was TeamViewer, which lounches a daemon that interferes with the graphic server...
the solution was disabling the TeamViewer daemon with following command:

```
teamviewer -daemon disable
```

Now the mouse moves smoothly and precisely in the screen...